# How do I know which answers, questions, comments were downvoted?

Tags: support, voting, down-votes

Now I know what your going to say right away, just look at stuff you might have recently answered, commented on or asked.

I did this but don't see any down votes and I knew how many up votes were given so the up vote counts didn't change. My reputation score dropped a couple of points, no biggie, but just wondering why. I looked in recent activity for my account and saw nothing and have just become confused as to why 2 rep points were shaved off.

But regardless, what if someone down voted you on something you asked, answered or commented on a while ago. Is there any way to know what was down voted?

Comment: I voted to close - this belongs on http://meta.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on the envelope, click on `Today` and click on the number of reputation gained. That will show upvotes, down votes, and accepted answer points separately.

This is only for your items however, not for things you commented on. At this time, the only way to see if threads you are interested in have been update is by clicking the star on a question to favorite it, and then check your favorites tab every so often. (Your Name on the top bar > Favorites)

Answer (score 2):

As well as the recent activity page, you might find my [Reputation Tracker](http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As Chacha102 say, the `Recent Activity` page is a good source for this info.  Also, on your user page, you can click on the `reputation` tab.  There you can see by date range what posts (questions and answers) garnered what sort of positive/negative reputaion.